# warning message after installing angular-ui-router

Tags: angularjs, npm

After i insalled angular-ui-router with npm install, it shows this message.

```
WARNING! this npm package "angular-ui-router" has been renamed to "@uirouter/angularjs".  Please update your package.json
See https://ui-router.github.io/blog/uirouter-scoped-packages/ for details.
C:\Users\amir\workspace\cata_service\src\main\resources\static
`-- angular-ui-router@1.0.3
  `-- @uirouter/core@5.0.3

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\amir\workspace\cata_service\src\main\resources\static\package.json'
npm WARN static No description
npm WARN static No repository field.
npm WARN static No README data
npm WARN static No license field
```

does anyone know what does it mean ?
.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The npm package is renamed from  angular-ui-router  to  @uirouter/angularjs 
You need to replace

```
 "dependencies": { "angular-ui-router": "latest", "ui-router-visualizer": "latest", }
```

by

```
"dependencies": { "@uirouter/angularjs": "latest", "@uirouter/visualizer": "latest", }
```